# SetWindowsHookEx stops receiving WH_MOUSE_LL events when window focus lost

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I have an SDL2 program that opens an SDL window. In the `main` I create a hook for mouse events as

```
hMSHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseProc, NULL, NULL);
```

while outside of the `main` I have the custom mouse event handler

```
HHOOK hMSHook;
int xPosAbsolute = 0;
int yPosAbsolute = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        auto &ms = *(const MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
        if (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            xPosAbsolute = ms.pt.x;
            yPosAbsolute = ms.pt.y;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hMSHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

When the window is in focus, the mouse coordinates `xPosAbsolute` and `yPosAbsolute` are properly updated as the mouse moves. However, if another window receives focus, these variables stop being updated.

My question is, how do I make `SetWindowsHookEx()` continue receiving `WH_MOUSE_LL` events while my window is not in focus?

EDIT:

Actually, as it turns out, `SetWindowsHookEx` only stopped receiving event updates when the window focus was lost to another window that was launched as administrator, while the SDL2 window of this program was launched as a regular user. Once the current program is launched as administrator as well, all updates continue to come in (using the above code), even when window focus is lost. So this turned out to be a non-issue.

Comment: For low-level hooks, the `hMod` parameter of `SetWindowsHookEx()` should be NULL, not `hInstance`. The [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) documentation even states this: "*The hMod parameter must be set to NULL [...] if the hook procedure is within the code associated with the current process.*"

Comment: That being said, consider using the [Raw Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) instead of `SetWindowsHookEx()`. The [`LowLevelMouseProc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/lowlevelmouseproc) documentation even states this: "*In most cases where the application needs to use low level hooks, it should monitor raw input instead.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for pointing this out. I fixed this in my code and in the question above. Unfortunately, the issue with `SetWindowsHookEx()` not receiving events when window focus is lost still persists.

Comment: Does the thread that is installing the hook have a message loop?  Low-level hook  events are run in the installing thread (which is why Raw Input is more efficient when hooking other apps), so that thread needs to have message processing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It does not, since `GetMessage` is blocking, while there is a loop to perform other functions. I'm not sure how to merge the two... Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with raw input to get it to do the equivalent.

Comment: "*It does not, since GetMessage is blocking*"" - `GetMessage()` will handle the `WH_MOUSE_LL` requests internally. If you have a `GetMessage()` loop, then you have a message loop for `SetWindowsHookEx()` to use.  "*Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with raw input to get it to do the equivalent*" - simply call `RegisterRawInputDevices()` for the desired mouse, giving it an `HWND` to send notifications to, and then you can handle `WM_INPUT` messages in your `HWND`'s message procedure, using `GetRawInputData()` to get the mouse data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau following your suggestion, I'm trying to make the raw input approach work. However, so far I do not seem to capture any events. Perhaps you could give me a hint on what is missing? I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454809/wm-input-does-not-receive-mouse-updates

Answer (score 0):

Focus is not required but keep pumping messages is required.

The following is a mini Win32 window application with low level hook you can refer to. It will receive WM_MOUSEMOVE message in all existing threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread regardless of which window holds the focus.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        auto& ms = *(const MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        if (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"\n WM_MOUSEMOVE \n");
            OutputDebugStringA(to_string(counter++).c_str());
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    HHOOK hMSHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseProc, NULL, NULL);

    WNDCLASSEXW wcex = {0};
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    RegisterClassExW(&wcex);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, L"test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I see this code creates a new window and has a blocking main message loop. In my case, I use SDL2 to create a window, and to use SDL functionality I'm using a different rolling cycle update loop. Is there a way to set a property for an existing window to continue receiving messages after focus is lost? Which line of your code is ensuring that property specifically?

Comment: @Kagaratsch *since GetMessage is blocking*, if the `GetMessage()` can't get executed continuously when the window lost focus, if this is true, we need find why `GetMessage()` blocks.