# WM_INPUT does not receive mouse updates

Tags: c++, wndproc

Outside of the `main`, I define a mouse event handler as

```
int xPosAbsolute = 0;
int yPosAbsolute = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_INPUT:
        {
            UINT dwSize = sizeof(RAWINPUT);
            static BYTE lpb[sizeof(RAWINPUT)];
            GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lparam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
            RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;
            if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
            {
                xPosAbsolute += raw->data.mouse.lLastX;
                yPosAbsolute += raw->data.mouse.lLastY;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

inside of the `main` I then register and bind the mouse readings as

```
POINT p;
if (GetCursorPos(&p))
{
    xPosAbsolute = p.x; 
    yPosAbsolute = p.y;
}
RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];
Rid[0].usUsagePage = HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC;
Rid[0].usUsage = HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE;
Rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
Rid[0].hwndTarget = hWnd;
RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 1, sizeof(Rid[0]));
```

Unfortunately, even if I move the mouse, the variables `xPosAbsolute` and `yPosAbsolute` never change their values from the initial `GetCursorPos` setting. Am I missing something in order to make the `WndProc` work?

EDIT:

Borrowing some of the ingredients from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb384843(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), I've included the following in the `main`

```
HMODULE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("win32app");
WNDCLASSEX wcex;
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, 
MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
```

to attempt to register `WndProc` with the window. Unfortunately, this did not give any improvement.

Comment: Your description of doing things in `main` suggests you are writing an application for the console.  Where is your code that actually _uses_ `WndProc`?  Are you creating a window at all?  Have you set a breakpoint in `WndProc` to see if _any_ events are being processed there?

Comment: @paddy Thank you for the comment! The application is for command line, but it also creates a SDL2 window (which is fed into `hWnd`). I just checked, and no events are reaching `WndProc`.

Comment: Again, I ask you: where is the code that tells Windows to use `WndProc` as your window procedure?

Comment: Also, your `WndProc()` is declared wrong, it needs the `CALLBACK` (`__stdcall`) calling convention. Allso, your `return 0;` statement should be inside the `case WM_INPUT` block, replacing the `break` statement.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I made changes to `WndProc` and included more code, see the edit. Unfortunately, it still does not work...

Comment: An important consequence of that misplaced return statement is that if this procedure is used during the creation of a window, it will return `FALSE` (0) for `WM_NCCREATE` and cause window creation to fail.

Comment: Why did you add `xPosAbsolute += 10;` for *every* message the window receives? That increment does not belong there.  In any case, you have registered a window class with `WndProc` associated with it, but where is your call to `CreateWindow/Ex()` to actually create an `HWND` that uses that window class? Step 3 in the "To add functionality to the WinMain function" section of the tutorial you linked to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The `xPosAbsolute += 10;` was just to see if any messages are arriving at all. I see, an issue is that the window is created by SDL2. I thought I could attach `WndProc` to it after it is created, but I see now that it's a wrong assumption. Perhaps I should try looking up how to use `WM_INPUT` specifically within the SDL2 framework.

Comment: @Kagaratsch you could grab the SDL window's underlying HWND and [subclass it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview), but I would suggest simply calling `CreateWindow/Ex()` directly to create a separate (message-only) HWND just for `RegisterRawInputDevices()` to use. You already have the majority of pieces in place for it, you are just missing that 1 function call.